# Problem with using TikZ in Texmaker

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, miktex, windows

I seem unable to use any TikZ command in Texmaker. Whenever I use such command, I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `tikz.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,or enter new name.
(Default extension: sty)Enter file name:! Emergency stop.<read > \usetikzlibrary
```

I'm also unable to download the package also. What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I suppose you have a MikTeX installation. Right?

Comment: You mention texmaker, but... Can you open a terminal and compile your document from there using `pdflatex yourdocument.tex`?

Comment: Run as administrator and let MikTeX install stuff.

Comment: yes,its MikTex.

Comment: i am unable to compile because of the error

Comment: I tried the run as administrator option, but still its unable to install the package

Answer (score 1):

I am using TexLive 2014  on  linux . I experienced same problem. 
The issue was resolved by adding  the following in bashrc
( the shell environment )

```
PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"
```

and updating actual paths in TexMaker Configuration

[image]